# How to get a date from day number and year?

Tags: ruby, date

I'm trying to convert a day number for a given year back into its date,  i.e. the inverse of the method `yday`.  For example, given the 200th day of the year 2012 I want to get the date 2012-07-18.

Comment: Give some sample examples...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a core feature of Date and DateTime.

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-ordinal

```
d = Date.ordinal( 2012, 200 )
=> #<Date: 2012-07-18 ((2456127j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

d = DateTime.ordinal( 2012, 200 )
=> #<DateTime: 2012-07-18T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456127j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Or just [`Date.ordinal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-ordinal)